# How come Android SDK installation did not work with the Eclipse repository download but did with manual Eclipse 3.6.2 download?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-10.04

I installed Eclipse from the repository using the synaptic package manager under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I had installed the SDK which I downloaded from Android developer site; [link to SDK download site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). And I subsequently tried to install the ADT plugin for eclipse [link to the installation instruction on the Dev page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#downloading), by inserting the appropriate address for new software

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

But trying to download the plugins created errors and did not proceed. I had even tried to insert the path to the SDK in the `bashrc` file in the home directory as recommended [here](http://androidforums.com/developer-101/2321-installing-eclipse-android-sdk-ubuntu-8-04-8-10-a.html).

In the end, I downloaded from the eclipse site Helios 3.6.2 and inserted the ADT plugin address which then proceeded without problems. It downloaded the SDK automatically, and did not even need to have downloaded the SDK myself or have added the path to the SDK in `.bashrc.`

So my question is why did the Eclipse version downloaded from the repository fail? It's version was within the working versions in the specifications. Also, why is the SDK prescribed as necessary to download prior to the ADT plugin, to be capable for Android development when in my case it was not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this is very simple. Eclipse in Ubuntu 10.04 repository is 3.5.x version. While the minimum version of Eclipse for SDK is 3.6 or greater. [Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) is the link to the system requirements

Answer (score 2):

Well I think downloading Eclipse from it's own site rather then from 3rd party repository will always get you the better (at least the most recent) version. It would have been strange if it were the other way around.

As for your second question: when you add the ADB plugin, you can tell it if you already have an Android SDK on your computer (and point it to the location) or ask it to get it's own version of the Android SDK (which it downloads to your Eclipse plugins directory). You can pretty much use either option here with the same end result

Comment: that makes sense, it is for me surprising that this is not recommended from the start and the pages I read do not explicitly recommend or advise this as a shorter procedure.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Besides, it takes a whole lot longer to download the ADB Plugin with the SDK. I think Google just wanted to make it more "automagical" and not have the user bothered with the small details.

Answer (score 1):

When you install eclipse via aptitude, it installs for all users with correspondent rights, for example, plugins are installed to `/usr/share/eclipse/plugins` and this directory have following access rights:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/share/eclipse/plugins
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 32768 2011-10-15 09:01 /usr/share/eclipse/plugins
```

Then, to install any plugins ( like ADT, for example ) from eclipse itself, you need to launch `eclipse` under proper user - alas, `eclipse` do not request necessary rights during plugin installation.

If you unpack tarball downloaded from http://www.eclipse.org somewhere in your home directory, you do it under current user, so all owner/groups for directories and files are set correspondently:

```
$ ls -ld ~/eclipse/plugins
drwxrwxr-x 22 darkmist darkmist 36864 2012-02-28 22:01 /home/darkmist/eclipse/plugins
```